# GNU make, implicit rules not needed

Tags: c, makefile, build, gnu-make

I have the following directory:

```
Makefile
src/
   main.c
   dummy.raw
   (main.o)    (<- to be built)
   (dummy.txt) (<- to be built)
build/
   (main)      (<- to be built)
```

And the following Makefile:

```py
C_FILES=$(wildcard src/*.c)
O_FILES=$(C_FILES:%.c=%.o)

main: build/main


build/main: $(O_FILES) 
    gcc $(O_FILES) -o build/main 


src/%.o: src/%.c src/dummy.txt
    echo "Compiling using my rule"
    gcc -c $< -o $@


src/%.txt: src/%.raw
    touch $@
    @echo "Created dummy file"


clean:
    rm -f src/*.o
    rm -f src/*.txt
    rm -f build/*
```

The problem is that `make` seems to ignore my rule for producing .o files and use its own built-in version ; in particular, it does not build `dummy.txt`. Here's a sample output:

```sh
$ make clean
rm -f src/*.o
rm -f src/*.txt
rm -f build/*
$ make
cc    -c -o src/main.o src/main.c
gcc src/main.o -o build/main
```

`make` only starts using the rule in the Makefile if I build the .txt file myself using `make src/dummy.txt`.

- Why is `make` behaving this way?
- How do I correct my Makefile to force `make` to build the intermediate `dummy.txt`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that your method invokes a chain of pattern rules, one to build `src/main.o` and one to build `src/dummy.txt`, and [Make will prefer an implicit rule to a chain of pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules).

There are a couple of ways to solve this. Two simple ones:

You could invoke Make with the [‘-r’ a.k.a. ‘--no-builtin-rules’ option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary):

```
make -r
```

Or you could hard-code the rule for `src/dummy.txt`:

```
src/%.txt: src/%.raw
    touch $@
    @echo "Created dummy file"

src/dummy.txt: src/dummy.raw
```

Comment: Or you can delete the built-in rule by adding it with no recipe: `%.o:%.c`.  Or you can delete almost all built-in rules, including these, by adding `.SUFFIXES:` with no suffix prerequisites to clear it.  Or, if you have GNU make 4.0 or better, you can add `MAKEFLAGS += -r` in your makefile and it will have the same effect as on the command line ... just a few other choices :)